# Count positional arguments in function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function signature:

```py
# my signature
def myfunction(x, s, c=None, d=None):
    # some irrelevant function body
```

I need the number of positional arguments. How can I return the number (2) of positional arguments (x & s). The number of keyword arguments is not relevant.

Comment: Why would you need the count of parameters at runtime?

Comment: I'm writing a package for the command line in which users can pass self-written functions to the api. Each number of positional arguments represent a different kind of function. Therefore I need to count the positional arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the number of all arguments (using `f.__code__.co_argcount`), the number of keyword arguments (using `f.__defaults__`), and subtract the latter from the former:

```
def myfunction(x, s, c=None, d=None):
  pass

all_args = myfunction.__code__.co_argcount

if myfunction.__defaults__ is not None:  #  in case there are no kwargs
  kwargs = len(myfunction.__defaults__)
else:
  kwargs = 0

print(all_args - kwargs)
```

Output:

```
2
```

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> `__defaults__`: A tuple containing default argument values for those arguments that have defaults, or `None` if no arguments have a default value.

and:

> `co_argcount` is the number of positional arguments (including arguments with default values);

Answer (score 3):

You could do that by using the `inspect` module like,

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(a, b, *, c=None):
...   print(a, b, c)
... 
>>> sig = inspect.signature(foo)
>>> sum(1 for param in sig.parameters.values() if param.kind == param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
2
```

The caveat is,

> Python has no explicit syntax for defining positional-only parameters,
>   but many built-in and extension module functions (especially those
>   that accept only one or two parameters) accept them.

Comment: Positional-only syntax via the special `/` marker was introduced by [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) in Python 3.8.